# Cannot see Azure resources in Visual Studio 2022 (17.5.3) Publish wizard

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-web-app-service, visual-studio-2022, azure-appservice

I've published my ASP.NET MVC web site to Azure App Service countless times. Today, though, when I tried to do so, I got a publish error. Thinking it might be related to a recent password change, I signed out of my Microsoft account and deleted my old publishing profile so I could start fresh.

However, now, **when I use the Publish wizard to set up a new publish profile, it won't even show me my Azure resources**. Here's what I'm doing:

1. Sign out of Microsoft account in Visual Studio.
2. Right-click web project > `Publish...`
3. Click `Add a publish profile`
4. Select `Azure` as the target
5. Select `Azure App Service (Windows)` as the specific target
6. The wizard asks me to sign in.
7. Sign in.
8. When the sign-in window goes away, the Publish window momentarily shows the UI for picking the target Azure App Service, but then it immediately switches back to the screen telling me to sign in.

Here are some images:

Prior to signing in...

[image: Prior to signing in]

For just a few moments after signing in...

[image: For just a few moment after signing in]

Immediately afterward...

[image: Afterward]

No matter what I do, I can't see my Azure resources. Is anyone else hitting this? Do I need to delete a folder somewhere to clear out some cruft? Thanks in advance?

Comment: Try clearing your Visual Studio cache and delete the previous credentails and the restart it and then re-give credentials

Comment: To delete cache go to ```%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio``` and clear all which starts with 17

Comment: Hello, @RithwikBojja. Thank you for the reply. Weirdly, when I got up this morning, the problem had gone away. I did notice a Windows Firewall dialog that I hadn't noticed last night, so perhaps some traffic was being blocked, but I didn't actually accept any changes, so that might be a red herring. Perhaps this was a temporary issue on the Azure side. At any rate, thank you again for the reply. I'll try deleting the cache as you suggest if it happens again!

Comment: Hi @BrianRak , Can you please let me know how it was resolved on your side, what you have changed in your Azure account or something else because I am facing this issue form the last one day, and still not resolved, visual studio version -  17.5.5 and trying with the azure free subscription.

Comment: I can't see them either. Tried clearing cache, sign out-in azure accounts, even re-installed VS, nothing works. Same symptoms, the empty list flashes for a half-seconds and then goes away to the "Immediately Afterward.." screen above. Running VS 17.5.5 community edition

Comment: To get around it I had to go to the webapp, select Download Publish Profile, then build a new Publish Profile in VS using the downloaded file.

Answer (score 1):

This type of issue occurs when there are any pending updates for the Visual Studio.

Check for the update, update / use any latest version of Visual Studio.

- Install the latest `Visual Studio` version by selecting Azure development.

[image]

- Check whether the `Azure Subscription` is in Active state by login in Azure Portal.
- In `Visual Studio` => `Tools` => `Options` => `Azure Service Authentication` => `Account Selection`, select the Azure account.

[image]

- In  VS,`File` => `Account Settings`, check the `Account options`.

[image]

- Here Iam using `VS 2022 17.5.0` version.
- Now, try to publish he Application, select `Azure App Service`=> click on `Create new` or `Create a new Instance`.

[image]

Comment: Hello, @Harshitha. Thank you very much for your reply. I was actually running the most recent update -- in fact, this started happening right after updating to 17.5.3. Fortunately, though, when I got up this morning, the problem had gone away. Perhaps there was a temporary error on the Azure side. At any rate, thank you again.

Comment: I still get this issue with VS2022 17.5.4

Comment: @DanNguyen - Please refer similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75953145/visual-studio-2022-caches-old-tenant-id-cant-get-rid-of-it/75963839#75963839).

Comment: Tried everything here and in the post referenced above by @Harshitha and nothing has worked. This didn't happen until I upgraded to 17.5.3, and continues with 17.5.4.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference I was having the exact same issue as above but it came down to my Azure Access Priveledges having being changed. Once the correct priveledges were restord to my Azure AD profile the visual studio plugin started to work again

Answer (score 0):

Try to set "**YES**" to Access management for Azure resources in the Azure portal.
Log in to the **Azure portal** > **Azure Active Directory**.

[image]

Now click on **Properties** and set **Access management for Azure resources** to **Yes**. I hope this will work. If this does not work then, click on **Manage security defaults** and set it to **Disabled** (Not recommended).

[image]

Now you can see the Azure resources.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the above answers with no luck. The only thing that helped was the work-around to download the publishprofiles from the Azure app service and use them. Now however, with VS 17.6.4 it works again. It appears the whole "publish" flow is a bit different in the new version and this finally fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, no azure subscription was showing despite being logged into my account and having a valid subscription. What I found that resolved it for me was ensuring that under account options `(Tools > Options > Environment > Accounts)` I had "Authenticate across all Azure Active Directories when adding accounts" selected. This wasn't selected under my sign in options, once I selected this I was able to access my Azure subscription from within Visual Studio.

[image: account sign in options]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I was trying to publish .NET core API to Azure from visual studio community edition in Mac, but my webapp was not appearing in my visual studio. Eventually I figure out I created my azure webapp in Linux OS, when I create new app in Windows OS it started appearing in my visual studio.

I am sure OS should not be a reason for this, or I need to do some settings in my visual studio which I am not aware of, but it is working what I wanted.

I am sharing my experience here, if it could help someone.

Thanks

Comment: I think that this might be a partial answer, but for that it should provide a solution for at least a part of the problem. Can you [edit] to make more obvious which part of the problem you have solved and how? I deally as much according to [answer] as possible. If you can not I recommend to delete this and use your commenting privilege to share your appreciated insight that way.