# Visual Studio 2022 Publish window is not detecting authentication state

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, visual-studio-2022

I am already signed in to VS2022, so into Azure too, but while trying to publish an App I have the screen below:

[image]

It is ok from the top right that I am signed in already. So while am I getting this?

I even tried suggestions from this [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vs-2022-1711-keep-asking-me-to-re-enter-credential/1691762): I signed out, and deleted `%localappdata%.IdentityService` folder, and signed in again. I got the same thing.

Please help.

Comment: Sometimes it happens with VS,temporarily.

Comment: Please refer similar issue [SOThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75882673/cannot-see-azure-resources-in-visual-studio-2022-17-5-3-publish-wizard)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will apply recommendations from that thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have mentioned, sometimes it can be a temporary issue which is caused by many reasons.

It can also be a temporary network/Azure issue.

I can see that you have logged in to Azure using your Personal MailID.
Make sure you have enough permissions to access the resources or able to Publish the Application.

Check your role in the Azure Portal.

In Visual Studio, Tools => Options, try to `Re-Authenticate` the existing Accounts.

- And make sure you have selected the correct Azure Subscription.

[image]

- If you still have issues in sign in, then we can use `Import Profile` option to Publish the `App Service`.
- We can see   it is not asking for any Visual Studio sign in .

[image]

- First create an App Service with the required runtime stack, Download the Publish profile from Azure App Service.

[image]

- Browse and upload the downloaded publish profile and continue.
  [image]

Refer similar issues addressed in [SOThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75953145/visual-studio-2022-caches-old-tenant-id-cant-get-rid-of-it/75963839#75963839).

Comment: Thanks, @Harshitha, After updating VS2022 and re-authenticating with MFA, it finally worked.

Answer (score 0):

Update Visual Studio, in VS go to `help` > `check for updates`

It was the only thing that helped in the end