# Visual Studio is not connecting with Microsoft Azure, for Publishing my App

Tags: azure, visual-c++, azure-devops, deployment, publish

Attached image shows the issue, even after signing in with my credentials it shows the same page, kind help I am really stuck for my app to deploy, your help will be appreciated. Is this a common issue while access Microsoft Azure

[image]

I was expecting a connection but it isn't happening, kindly help me out

Comment: Please refer [SOThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75965004/visual-studio-2022-publish-window-is-not-detecting-authentication-state/75976386#75976386)

Answer (score 0):

Try running VScode in admin mode, if that's not the case try and create the App service first in Azure (i.e. separately to VS), then select existing app service in VS.
If you don't see the App service at first, try again after some time as it may be due to latency in its deployment in Azure.