# Visual Studio 2022 / ASP.NET Core Web API: Azure deployment blocked on App Service tab

Tags: azure, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) v17.5.3, I created a basic ASP.NET Core Web API project.

I right click, on publish/ add a publish profile /

```
Target : Azure
Specific target : Azure App Service Linux
```

And then I am blocked on "App Service":

[image]

When I click "Sign in", I don't have a failure or a success screen, I am just stuck at the Sign in screen.

Do you know how to publish my app to Azure please?

Comment: it is a temporary issue reference [SOTread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75882673/cannot-see-azure-resources-in-visual-studio-2022-17-5-3-publish-wizard)  and please check if new [update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75965004/visual-studio-2022-publish-window-is-not-detecting-authentication-state/75976386#75976386) able in [VS2022](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75953145/visual-studio-2022-caches-old-tenant-id-cant-get-rid-of-it/75963839#75963839)

Answer (score 0):

As I have mentioned, there are several factors that can contribute to it occasionally being a transient problem.

Verify any updates in Visual Studio, Azure development and logging into the Azure Portal will allow you to check the Azure Subscription's status, your role.
[Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YpXu.png)=>Get Tools and [features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbB3C.png).

- In visual studio [selection tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOb49.png) and option

[image]

- Select the subscription and Azure app [service Linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZRSF.png).

[image]

- Other method is with [import profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vM4fm.png) in [visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CT2Ic.png).
- Resetting all the setting of visual studio (or) remove logged in [accounts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5PCA.png).

[image]

- If the problem still exists, uninstall Visual Studio and reinstall it using the most recent version from the Visual Studio official website.

Reference:

For much more reference check below.

- SOTread by @[Jahnavi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75953145/visual-studio-2022-caches-old-tenant-id-cant-get-rid-of-it/75963839#75963839)
- [Issues signing in to Visual Studio subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/subscriptions/sign-in-issues)
- [Azure App Service using Visual Studio](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/app-service/troubleshoot-dotnet-visual-studio.md)